# What type of adjective is "aesthetic"?

Tags: adjectives

(This is coming from a discussion over at ELL, but the specific nuance below fits here I think).

Consider two statements about a dog:

1. The dog has brown fur
2. The dog has aesthetic appeal

and two alternate formulations:

3. The dog's fur is brown
4. The dog's appeal is aesthetic

Is it simply idiom, or is there something technical about the role of "aesthetic" in the underlying proposition that makes 4 rarely if ever used?

Comment: The alternate formulations are not identical in meaning with the originals. #1 means that *some* of the dog's teeth are sharp; #3 means they all are. If we substitute, let us say, a weapon for the dog in #2 and #4, this difference becomes more pronounced. The appeal of a weapon to a potential purchaser may be partly aesthetic but partly a matter of efficacy. If so, that rules out #4 as inaccurate. If we in turn substitute a sculpture, as something likely to have *only* aesthetic appeal, #4 ceases to require the adjective at all: the sculpture would merely be said to be appealing.

Comment: Changed to avoid that irrelevant difference.

Comment: I don't find Sentence 4 that unusual.  The dog's appeal is aesthetic; i.e. we like the way it looks.  Money's appeal is practical; i.e. we'd like it whether it's a pretty hundred dollar bill or an ugly one.

Comment: The variety of modification between the adjective and the noun it refers to is the same in each formulation. But that's because _aesthetic appeal_ and _brown fur_ actually mean something. If you swap them, you won't repeat the results: _aesthetic fur_ and _brown appeal_ are both problematic, and display the same problems in _The dog's fur is aesthetic_ and _The dog's appeal is brown._

Comment: @John Lawler - the difference I take from the two alternatives is, in "The dog has aesthetic appeal" the appeal of the dog is not exclusively aesthetic; whereas in, "The dog's appeal is aesthetic" the dog's appeal is exclusively aesthetic. Is this semantically correct/incorrect?

Comment: Overall, regardless of the *fact* that there's a difference, what I was hoping for was either a technical explanation -- e.g. **"Well it's because 'aesthetic' in this context is acting as proto-reflexive third-declension mono-fartic adjectoid"** -- or a simple **"cuz that's the idiom dude"**

Comment: There are dozens -- maybe hundreds -- of ways an adjective can modify a noun, semantically. Colors are themselves a special grammatical category, for instance, and abstract adjectives like _aesthetic_ hafta be interpreted in the context of the utterance, the speakers, and the particular noun involved. _Appeal_ is itself a very high-level abstraction, and modifying it with another is not something that can be described simply as applying a tangential mollifier to the left quasi-martingale, or some such. But if it's terminology you want, we **can** dazzle you.

Comment: I see the same difference as @LittleEva. But it doesn't come from the adjective _aesthetic_ as much as from the way _appeal_ is generally used. You could substitute some other adjective into those sentences, and the distinction would be similar.

Comment: I am not equipped to answer provide the technical answer you seek, in fact your question raised further questions for me (my commentary to Mr. Lawler); @Barmar, whereas the distinction for me seemed to be  the result of the use of "has", and then "is".

Comment: @LittleEva But that distinction isn't parallelled in the sentences about fur color.

Comment: Yeah, @Barmar, you're right, I'm just saying that after your comment I went back to scrutinize and it seemed to me that I was sensing a distinction based on the change from "has" to "is". I'm not learned enough to well articulate why. Is it just me or do you follow?